# Unable to install CASdatasets package

Tags: r, installation, r-package

**I use these code to install CASdatasets:**

```
install.packages("xts")
install.packages("sp")
install.packages("CASdatasets", repos = "http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/", type="source")
```

**The error message is:**

```
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/src/contrib/CASdatasets_1.0-11.tar.gz' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 3860953 != reported length 119516409
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/src/contrib/CASdatasets_1.0-11.tar.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
```

The R version I used is R version 4.2.1.

How can I install the CASdatasets package?

Any help here is truly needed and is well appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you that the file took too long to download and so it timed out after 60 seconds. If you read the help for `download.file` using `?download.file`, it tells you how to increase the timeout using _e.g._ `options(timeout = max(300, getOption("timeout")))`.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. I was able to resolve the issue by installing it manually.